# Canvas not drawing image in js. (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

I want to create an inventory system. First it is drawing the basic inventory without items.
After that it is check if the user has got item, then draw it on the empty squares.
The items are located in ./cdn/items/ .

I have an item in my database, but the code is only drawing the empty inventory without items.

```
  const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const logo = await Canvas.loadImage('./cdn/atransparent.png');
  //item id
  const item = [
    await Canvas.loadImage('./cdn/items/key.jpg')

  ]

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#2c2f33";

  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(55+(i%10)*60, (((((Math.floor(i/10)+1)-1)*6)+1)*10), 50, 50);
  }

  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
  ctx.drawImage(logo, 250, 25, 200, 200);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;

  ctx.translate(10,250);
  ctx.rotate(-0.5*Math.PI);
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText(message.author.username , 125, 27.5);
  ctx.restore();

  db.query(`SELECT * FROM economy WHERE member_id = ${message.author.id}`, (err, rows) => {
    console.log(`[INVENTORY] Adatok lekérdezése ${message.author.id} számára...`)
    let items = rows[0].items.trim().split(',');
    console.log(`[INVENTORY] ${message.author.id} inventoryjának tartalma: ${items}`);

      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(item[items[i]], 55+(i%10)*60, (((((Math.floor(i/10)+1)-1)*6)+1)*10), 50, 50);
        }

      }
    )

  const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
  message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} Inventory-ja`, attachment);

  }
```

In the array there is one item with the item[0] variable, my item id in th database is 0, so it need to draw it out.
[my id is 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyr52.png)
Idk what is the problem...

Thanks, and Happy New Year!
Mark

Comment: [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/773178349371654144/794961291625758751/welcome-image.png) And here is the empty inventory, thats what i got.